# How to compare two lists of different length and map the items based on count

Tags: python-2.7

I have two lists of different lengths and i want match the items based on their actual relation. One list is the secondary structure elements and other list is aligned sequence. I want to match the secondary structure to its residues in the other list. And adjust the length of secondary structure by inserting '-' to that of gaps in the aligned sequence. The items in ss corresponds to RRCAVVTG in seq.

```
ss=['-', '-', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S']
seq≈["---------------RRCAVVTG"]
for m in seq:
        found=[i for i in list(m)]
sscount=0
sscount1=0
for  char,ssi in zip(found,ss): 

    if char!='-'  :
        print char , sscount, ssi
        sscount+=1

    else:
        print char, sscount1, '#'
        sscount1+=1
```

The expected results:

```
---------------##EEEESS

---------------RRCAVVTG
```

But i get the following results:

```
 - 0 #
 - 1 #
 - 2 #
 - 3 #
 - 4 #
 - 5 #
 - 6 #
 - 7 #
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood the question right. First we fill the string `ss` with `-` and then compare it to the string inside `seq` using `zip()`:

```
ss = ['-', '-', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'E', 'S', 'S']

seq = ["---------------RRCAVVTG"]

out = ''
for ch1, ch2 in zip('{:->{}}'.format(''.join(ss), len(seq[0])), seq[0]):
    if ch1=='-' and ch2 !='-':
        out += '#'
    elif ch1=='-' and ch2 == '-':
        out += '-'
    else:
        out += ch1

print(out)
print(seq[0])
```

Prints:

```
---------------##EEEESS
---------------RRCAVVTG
```

Comment: Thanks Andrej for answering my question. In the alignment where ever the gap comes, the letter in ss should be adjusted in the same order of character in seq. However i was able to solve it, Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0):

```
for m in seq:
    found=[i for i in list(m)]
sscount=0
sscount1=0
num=0
for  char,ssi in zip(found,itertools.cycle(ss)): 

    if char!='-'  :
        print char , sscount, ss[num]
        d.append(ss[num])
        num+=1
        sscount+=1

    else:
        print char, sscount1, '#'
        sscount1+=1
```

Comment: Above is the script that gives expected output. If anyone has the most efficient code or suggestion than above, please post!